# How to display data that was web scrape on a web page?

Tags: node.js, web, web-scraping, puppeteer, browserify

I am trying to build a web page that will display data that is collect with web scraping.
I manage to scrape the data with nodejs, while using the module puppeteer to do so.
When i wanted to display this in a web page i found out that i could not because puppeteer module cannot be run on a browser. After some research i found browserfiy module that supposed to allow me to do what i wanted, but eventually i realized that i cannot use browserfiy with puppeteer.
How can i do this?

Are there any other modules that i can use that can work wil browserify?

Is there other way to do this that will allow me to run it on the browser?

I do not want to use APIs.

Comment: Is it only commercial APIs you oppose or do you want to avoid making your own API too?

Comment: I am pretty new to this area so i am not sure what you mean about my API. I do not want to use APIs that certain sites supply like amazon and google ( i guess this is commercial APIs)

Comment: You could have one backend which serves your website and then another backend which doesn't run on the browser but scrapes the page on request.

Comment: Do you mean that one will run locally (on localhost) and will display the data there, and the other one will run the web?